# Inserting html in Outlook via VBA

Tags: html, vba, email, outlook

I would like to be able to send an html email from my Outlook mail account which explains how to open the developer tab in Outlook and using the macro editor I have followed the instructions (from [Outlook apps](http://www.outlook-apps.com/insert-html-to-outlook-emails/)) but have got stuck with my code.

My code is;

```
Sub InsertHTMLFile()
Dim insp As Inspector
Set insp = ActiveInspector
If insp.IsWordMail Then
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Set wordDoc = insp.WordEditor
wordDoc.Application.Selection.InsertFile “C: UsersPreeceyDesktoppaper_Jan.html“ , , False, False, False
End If
End Sub
```

I get error `5273 the document name or file path is not valid.`

I have tried using this path `file:///C:/Users/Preecey/Desktop/paper_Jan.html` but then I get; `Compile error: Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement`

I think I have the file path wrong but I don't know what it should look like.  I've looked for hours for solutions but so far I'm none the wiser.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks, Kerry

Comment: `C:\Users\Preecey\Desktop\paper_Jan.html`

Answer (score 3):

Replace the “C: UsersPreeceyDesktoppaper_Jan.html“ quotation marks with regular quotation marks "".

““ vs. ""

Hope this helps